# Get source of blur when invoked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur, onblur

I have a form (for user registration) that's paginated via splitting it up into divs that are hidden/displayed with .slideUp()/.slideDown(). It all works pretty well, but I want to validate each page with javascript before they proceed to the next page to reduce the number of errors that come back from the server-side validation. Right now I have them set to validate onblur. To check all the elements when the "next" button is clicked, I want to use .blur() to force it to validate each input, but I'm getting an error. An example of my onblur function is:

```
var validateEmpty = function() {
    var $src = $('.registrationPage #' + event.srcElement.id);
    validate($src, "Can't be left empty!", checkEmptyRequired);
}
```

It's being bound by setting the `onblur` attribute to the function.

Where validate is a function that takes a jQuery object, an error message, and a function that returns a boolean. The error I get is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'srcElement' of undefined
```

So it seems clear to me that .blur() doesn't trigger a javascript event and simply calls the onblur function. How can I get the id of a blurred element in a way that will work both when blurred normally (by losing focus in the page) and with .blur()?

Comment: How are you binding this event?

Comment: <input name="data[User][username]" onblur="validateEmpty()" maxlength="220" type="text" id="UserUsername" required="required"/>

It's set as the onblur attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You're not showing us how the function is called, but you should probably pass the event as a parameter, otherwise it will be undefined in some browsers (but not in IE):

```
var validateEmpty = function(event) {
    var $src = $('.registrationPage #' + event.target.id);
    validate($src, "Can't be left empty!", checkEmptyRequired);
}
```

that would work with something like:

```
$('.elements').on('blur', validateEmpty);
```

Also, `srcElement` is rarely used (it's IE specific), I think jQuery normalized `target`, but you could always do something like this to make sure:

```
var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

It looks like your code is written to work in Internet Explorer only ?

Comment: I'm actually just new to web development, I poked around briefly and srcElement was the first thing I found that looked right. It works in all the browsers I've tried, but it's not being properly triggered by $('element').blur()

Comment: I changed it to event.target.id, but it still has the same problem. It works when tabbing through the inputs but event is undefined when .blur() is called with jQuery.

Comment: Called how, as in triggered? IF so, there is no user event, you just triggered it ?

Comment: It would be called when they clicked the "next" button or hit enter, both of which call a JS function to show the next "page", a hidden `<div>`. I want to validate on blur or when the page is changed.

Comment: And how do you call the validateEmpty function? to have an event target, the event must originate from somewhere, otherwise you'll have to pass the elements yourself as the parameter!

Comment: It's called onblur, `onblur="validateEmpty()"`. I'd hoped that .blur() would behave in the same was as a blur event, but evidently that isn't the case. Any suggestions on how to pass the element as a parameter without screwing up the blur event behavior?

Comment: `onblur="validateEmpty(this)"` passes the element the inline handler is attached to.